# Prove that T1+T2 and cT1 are linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Sorry to ask two questions in a day, but I was struggling with this problem. I'm probably overthinking it.

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformations from V into W, verify that $T_1+T_2$ and $cT_1$ are linear transformations.

The book said that it should be fairly simple, and it seems simple, but wouldn't I need example vectors to figure out if $T(u)+T(v)=T(u+v)$ and $cT_1(u)=T_1(cu)$? Unless I could use any vector?

Comment: You need to prove certain equations for _every_ (pair of) vector(s). So just assume $u,v$ are given to you, and try to obtain the desired equations (not exactly the ones you wrote) using the equations you know to hold for $T_1$ and $T_2$ (since these are _given_ to be linear transformations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you want to show 
$$
(T_1 + T_2)(u + v) = (T_1 + T_2)u + (T_1 + T_2)v
$$ 
for all $u,v \in V$, and 
$$
(T_1 + T_2)(cu) = c(T_1 + T_2)(u)
$$
for all $u\in V$ and all scalars $c$.

So you want to $\textit{avoid}$ using example vectors, because you want to verify the properties for $\textit{every}$ vector. We could prove the first part in the following way: 
$$
(T_1 + T_2)(u + v) = T_1(u + v) + T_2(u + v)
$$
This by the definition of the sum of two transformations. Then the linearity of $T_1$ and $T_2$ kicks in:
$$
T_1(u + v) + T_2(u + v) = T_1(u) + T_1(v) + T_2(u) + T_2(v)
$$
Then, group the transformations being applied to $u$ and $v$:
$$
T_1(u) + T_1(v) + T_2(u) + T_2(v) = (T_1 + T_2)u + (T_1 + T_2)v
$$
Putting it all together gives us:
$$
(T_1 + T_2)(u + v) = (T_1 + T_2)u + (T_1 + T_2)v
$$
Verifying the other property is similar, and verifying both properties for $cT_1$ is the same as well.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This really cleared everything up!